# Debugging credential provider crash

Tags: windows, credential-providers, winlogon

I am developing a credential provider for windows. I would like to know if it’s possible to attach and debug while running. As this is part of a logon process I am not sure if/how to do it.

Also, if a credential provider crashes, does windows dump a core like Linux does?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke your credential provider using simple call to credentials API  `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW`. See MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsw) for detailed description.

I have been creating my own simple [application](https://github.com/alexyack/CredentialProviders/blob/a160c407e1049995c21c12e99c9979ba2d6e69b5/SampleCredentialInvoker/SampleCredentialInvoker.cpp#L192) to do this call.
It is tuned to call Windows Security Dialog with my own suggestions and options (`CREDUIWIN_IN_CRED_ONLY` flag in my case).
You can modify invocation flags to approximate your scenario.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke and run webview from inside the Cred Prov? I mean something like this? https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Comment: You can obtain a Window Handle (`HWND`) and create your own window(s).    Have a look at method [ICredentialProviderCredentialEvents::OnCreatingWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovidercredentialevents-oncreatingwindow)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way debug credential provider is to setup it on some other machine and use remote debug tools to attach to LogonUI.exe.